# Who currently owns the rights to the The 39 Clues movie?

Tags: copyright, the-39-clues

The *The 39 Clues* film has been talked about and speculated about since 2008, when Dreamworks/Steven Spielberg bought the rights.

Over the years, a few times we've heard random snippets such as who was hired to direct it.

In 2013, [Slashfilfm tells](http://www.slashfilm.com/universal-could-take-the-39-clues-from-steven-spielberg-and-dreamworks/) us...

> Five years have passed since Dreamworks purchased *The 39 Clues* and it seems like the rights are about to lapse. Cue Universal, who is in talks to buy the rights *The 39 Clues*.

Googling, and hanging around on the official T39C website for the past 4 years, I haven't heard anything about them actually buying the rights, though.

Does Dreamworks still own the rights? Did Universal buy them? Something else?

Comment: Wikipedia says Universal has them, but nothing official to confirm it.

Comment: @Edlothiad The wiki article sources from the OPs Slashfilm link.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot And two other "sources" which just seem to be random claims.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2015, Universal owns them, alongside most other Scholastic rights. But in 2015 - way later than the 2013 article you quoted. [Deadline.com](https://deadline.com/2015/03/universal-pictures-scholastic-deborah-forte-clifford-movie-1201389882/) reported on the deal:

> Universal Pictures has inked a three-year first look production deal with Scholastic Inc. and Deborah Forte to develop and produce live-action features from the publisher’s well known titles.  Currently in development at the studio is a big screen version of Scholastic’s Clifford, The Big Red Dog and The 39 Clues, with Forte serving as producer on both.